# Singleton object and subclasses

Tags: vb.net, singleton

I have a class called dRow that contains some data. I have many subclasses of dRow, AccountRow, PageRow, etc. They differ *only in code*. Now I'd like to add a singleton to dRow...

```
Protected Shared EmptyRow as dRow
```

EmptyRow is an instance of dRow that contains no data. Right below is this...

```
Public Function EmptyRow() as dRow...
```

Now the problem... I need AccountRow to return EmptyRow as an AccountRow, not a dRow...

```
Friend Function EmptyRow() as AccountRow...
```

DirectCast won't work, that's the wrong direction. It *looks* like I have to have a separate EmptyRow for each subclass?

Is there any way to avoid that fate?

Comment: Correct; `EmptyRow` cannot have two unrelated types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics might work. Are you creating instances of `dRow` or is it only used as a base class? If it's only a base class (could have `MustInherit` keyword) then try something like this:

```
MustInherit Class dRow(Of T As New)
    Protected Shared _emptyRow As New T

    Public Shared Function EmptyRow() As T
        Return _emptyRow
    End Function

End Class

Class AccountRow 
    Inherits dRow(Of AccountRow)

End Class

Class PageRow
    Inherits dRow(Of PageRow)

End Class
```

The `EmptyRow` function will now return the singleton instance of the subclass type.

You can even add a further generic type constraint like this to make sure sub classes only use an instance of `dRow` as their type.

```
MustInherit Class dRow(Of T As {dRow(Of T), New})
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79.aspx

Comment: Ah ha! That does look like a solution. I've never used generics before, I'm going to give this a whirl!

Comment: This is kind of a funny use of generics, but they can be very powerful.